# C# program keep on running despite no error

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Am working in a project where I should give a crystal reports RPT file as input and get the properties of that report.

I am facing a problem in loading the report itself so I have used `isLoaded()` function to check whether the report is loaded or not.

I have used the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Web;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;

namespace sampleretreival
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public string flName;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Retrieve.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (lstFiles.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                Retrieve.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Retrieve.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

        private void Browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog1.Multiselect = false;
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "Crystal Report Files | *.rpt";
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            flName = openFileDialog1.FileName;

            if (flName.Length != 0)
            {
                lstFiles.Items.Insert(0, flName);
                Retrieve.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select the crystal report files for analysis.", "SAMPLE", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                Browse.Focus();
            }
        }

        private void Retrieve_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int a=1;
            ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
            rpt.Load(flName);
            int count = 5;

            if (rpt.IsLoaded)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(count.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(a.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After compiling, I clicked the Browse button to select the report from the disk but when I click Retrieve button, the program keeps on running. I am not getting any output or any error.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code in the debugger?

Comment: Is the retrieve button wired up to the `Retrieve_Click` method? Did you double click on the retrieve button and have Visual Studio create an event handler for you?

Comment: @Tim Yup i ve tried tat too...but after i click retrieve button,it is going nowhere.

Comment: @KarlAnderson Yeah i have done like tat oly.

Comment: Please step through your code and tell us, what happens when you reach `Retrive_Click()` I get the feeling, either you don't reach that method or flName is empty at that point

Comment: @serv i ve used F11 to step through the code.flName is getting the value but when i click retrieve button control is not reachin inside Retrieve_click() function and it is going nowhere.

Comment: @Dinesh Are you certain, Retrieve_Click is a registered Eventhandler for the onClick event of your button? Double Check for spelling errors.

Comment: @Serv yeah am sure and ve checked it now also.